# How to pass a json object to a method in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying pass a JSON object to a method in asp.net mvc 4 but it always return null.

How could I do this ?

trying

**Asp.Net Method**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public JsonResult doLoginApp(string model){                     
        jsonResposta.Add("status", "1");
        jsonResposta.Add("email", model);
        return Json(jsonResposta);
    }
```

**JSON Object**

```
{"User": {"email":"myemail@domain.com", "password":"xxxxx"}};
```

**Return**

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "email": null
}
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost:14807/User/doLoginApp
```

**Edit Post**

**Model**

```
public class UserJsonModel{

    public long id                  { get; set; }         
    public String nome              {   get;set;}            
    public String email             {get;set;}    
    public String senha             {get;set;}   
    public int status               { get; set; } //1 ativo, 2 inativo, 0 aguardando
    public int tipo                 { get; set; } //1 painel, 2 aplicativos
    public String imagem            { get; set; }
    public int loginBy              { get; set; } //0 app, 1 facebook
    public UserJsonModel() { }

}
```

**Asp.NET method**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doLoginApp(UserJsonModel model){
        jsonResposta.Add("status", "1");
        jsonResposta.Add("email", model.email);
        return Json(jsonResposta);
    }
```

Comment: To start, your JSON object isn't just a string. You need a C# model that matches your JSON object. [http://json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/) would be helpful for figuring out what that model might look like. Two other things that could also cause problems are your RouteConfig.cs and whatever is making the request. Are you using AJAX?

Comment: With Ajax it works however in this post I'm trying send the Json object from an Android app.

Comment: Ok I gotcha, I'm not well versed with Java so I won't be much help there but creating the C# model is a good place to start. Since it's returning _something_ even though it's not what you expected that means that routing is finding the method you want to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a Model that map your json object and define in your method how you will pass the object (ex from body)

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doLoginApp([FromBody] MyModel model){                     
    jsonResposta.Add("status", "1");
    jsonResposta.Add("email", model);
    return Json(jsonResposta);
}
```

And search in java how to make HttpRequest Post and sent data in body, and it will work.

Comment: I edited the post with a Model, but the email still returning null. There's any way to receive the JSON Object directly without use `[FromBody]` ?

Comment: the problem not in this method but in How you call it from Java app, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700391/send-post-requests-with-body-in-android